# system2 functioning in R

Tags: r, system2

When I run a batch file through system2 in R:

The following runs the batch file without any issue:

```
system2("Run.bat")
```

However, this one gives an error:

```
system2("Run", stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
Warning message:
running command '"Run.bat"' had status 1
```

Any insights on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system2.html) carefully:

> `stdout`, `stderr`
>   where output to ‘stdout’ or ‘stderr’ should be sent. Possible values are "", to the R console (the default), NULL or FALSE (discard output), TRUE (capture the output in a character vector) or a character string naming a file.

Seems like you need to specify those arguments as character strings.