# R extensions: calling an external script within a package

Tags: php, r

I'm writing an R package which, among other things, defines a function which is actually a wrapper for a PHP script. Let's assume the PHP script offers some functionality that is considerably difficult to recreate in R and that my line of reasoning (wrapping a PHP script in R) makes sense.

I'm currently keeping the PHP script in a separate file, and running it via a system call.

My R function/wrapper looks like this:

```
wrapper <- function() {

  # I'm not entirely sure what the path to the PHP file should be
  php_file_name <- "magic_in.php"
  php_script_argument <- "hello, world"

  system_call <- sprintf('php -f "%s"', php_file_name, php_script_argument)
  system(system_call)

}
```

while the `magic_in.php` file is the following:

```
<?php

    print($argv[1]."\n")

?>
```

But this solution sucks - the system call works only if I have the PHP script in my current working directory.

I keep the wrapper in a `~/simple_package/R/wrapper.R` file, but I'm not sure where to store the PHP script.

Am I supposed to keep the PHP file in a `~/simple_package/src` directory and then call it using some dedicated R function (like `.Call` for C executables)?

Comment: Indeed, that's more suitable.

Comment: It seems that the `scripts` directory (folder?) is NOT persistent in Windows. But the `exec` (as suggested by hute37 in his answer) directory/folder IS persistent.

Comment: I tested that and it seems that no, not all secondary level directories are persistent, even if they aren't empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `/data` is not the best option for package scripts, `/exec` could be a better choice.

See:

- [Is there any special functionality in R package “exec” or “tools” directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104709/is-there-any-special-functionality-in-r-package-exec-or-tools-directories)

You may also consider using `system2`:

- [system2 functioning in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554628/system2-functioning-in-r)
- [Capture both exit status and output from a system call in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014081/capture-both-exit-status-and-output-from-a-system-call-in-r)

For some languages (Python), there is some special support in CRAN

- [rPython: Package Allowing R to Call Python](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html)

---

An example (using `system` and `system.file`):

- http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/exec-subdirectory-of-a-package-td924560.html

It is executed by an *external* R script command-line:

```
#!/bin/env Rscript

args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
if( length(args) < 2 ){
    stop( "usage : R CMD execute package script [parameters]\n" )
}
package <- args[1]
script <- args[2]
scriptfile <- file.path( system.file( "exec", script, package = package ) ) # <= path
if( !file.exists( scriptfile ) ){
    stop( sprintf( "file not found: '%s' ", scriptfile  ) )
}

trail <- if( length(args) > 2 ) paste( tail( args, -2 ), sep = " " ) else ""
cmd <- sprintf( '"%s" %s', scriptfile, trail )

system( cmd ) # <= or system2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of ways of doing this. You could hard-code the function into the script, write it to a file, run it through a function `wrapper` with arguments (path is implicit when you create the file) and clean up afterwards.

A better approach would probably be to put the script in `/data` and call it via `?system.file`.

Comment: It worked! The `data` directory is "persistent" (copied into the package's installation directory) unlike the `src` directory I tried initially.